# Finding the number of sequences in an arithmetic sequence. Exponential equation (?)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the value of sequence 1 (a1) and the difference between each sequence (d).
a1 = 1 and d = 7. I have the sum of the arithmetric sequence (Sn) which is 1350.

The task is to find the number of sequences. In other words, I need to solve for n by using the formula for Sn knowing that it equals 1350.

So I know Sn = 1350 and I need to find the formula for Sn involving "n" to get an equation involving n.

The formula for Sn is Sn = n*(a1+an) over 2.

So I need an. The formula for an = a1 + (n-1) * d, which means an = 7n-6.

Giving me Sn = n*(1+(7n-6)) over 2, which means Sn = (7n^2 - 5n) over 2.

And since I know Sn is 1350, that gives me the equation:

(7n^2 - 5n) over 2 = 1350

Multiply by 2 on each side..

7n^2 - 5n = 2700

or 7n^2 - 5n - 2700 = 0

Tedious introduction aside, basically I need to learn how to solve an equation like that.

The cheat sheet in my book gave me an "explanation" that I couldn't understand at all. (Task 1.44 http://sinuss2.cappelendamm.no/c383042/binfil/download.php?tid=365232)

Any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: looks like you have done everything correctly ( except you keep using the word "sequence" when you mean to say "term in the sequence"

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a quadratic equation, which are of the general form $ax^2+bx+c = 0$.  There is a general [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) (which is used in the linked cheat sheet) for the solutions to such an equation, namely
$$ x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
In your case this will yield
$$n = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{25+75600}}{14} = \frac{5\pm 275}{14}$$
Of these two solutions, it is clear that only $n = 20$ makes sense.

Comment: THANK YOU. Just knowing what that type of equation is called helped immensely (because now I can look up extensive tutorials on it if I need to). I love how my book on chapter one just starts using quadratic equations like wildfire without even running through it once. Thanks for helping me out :)